# Verify $(2r\sin A\cos A)^2+r^2(\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A)^2=r^2$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I verify this confounding identity:

$$(2r\sin A\cos A)^2+r^2(\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A)^2=r^2.$$

I know that

$$\sin 2\theta = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta$$

and that

$$\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = \cos 2\theta,$$

but in my problem there is an $r$ variable, so I am not sure how to proceed and make the left side equal $r^2$.

Comment: Try two things: (1) Use mathjax to format your questions. (2) Multiply out the terms in your identity.

Comment: hint: put $r$ outside of the parenthesis $\to r^2\ $!

Comment: $(a b )^2 = a^2 b^2$. Ulfric you need to do a little work, at least.

Comment: I shall but unfortunately I am not sure how to use mathjax

Comment: Ok I am not sure if I did this correctly.I did r(4sin^2Acos^2A)+r^2(cos2A)(cos2A)

Comment: So know would I end up having (r)(sin2A)(Sin2A)+r^2(cos2A)(cos2A)=r^2

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak The second part is correct, but would probably be better written as $r^2\cos^22A$.  As for the first part, you forgot to square the r, but you probably should rewrite it first using your identity you mentioned earlier.

Comment: On the left hand side, you'd end up with $r^2\sin2A\sin2A+r^2\cos2A\cos2A$. This can be written as $r^2\sin^22A+r^2\cos^22A$. Now use the distributive law to write this as $r^2(\sin^22A+\cos^22A)$. There is one step remaining to get what you want, and it should be an obvious one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about the "$r$"'s. Let them hang along for the ride. Think of $r$ as just a specific number, if you like.

Let's start with the left hand side of your identity:
$$\tag{1}
(\color{maroon}2r\color{maroon}{\sin A\cos A})^2+r^2(\color{darkgreen}{\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A})^2
$$
and apply the double angle identities you've noted. Replacing, as we may, in $(1)$ the expression $\color{maroon}{2\sin A\cos A}$ with $\sin (2A)$ and the expression $\color{darkgreen}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}$ with $\cos( 2A)$ we obtain
$$\tag{2}
\bigl(r\sin( 2A)\bigr)^2 +r^2\bigl(\cos(2A)\bigr)^2
$$

Using the rule $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ and the notations $(\sin x)^2=\sin^2x$ and  $(\cos x)^2=\cos^2 x$, we can write $(2)$ as
$$
\tag{3}
r^2\sin^2(2A)+r^2\cos^2(2A).
$$
Next, let's factor the $r^2$ term out. We can write $(3)$ as
$$\tag{4}
r^2\bigl(\sin^2 (2A)+\cos^2(2A)\bigr).
$$
But Pythagoras tell us that $\sin^2 (2A)+\cos^2 (2A)=1$; thus the expression in $(4)$ is simply $r^2$, which is what you wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Double angle identities do shorten the calculation, but are unnecessary.  Note that we are looking at 
$$r^2\left(4\sin^2 A\cos^2 A +(\cos^2A-\sin^2 A)^2\right).\tag{$1$}$$
The following non-trigonometric identity is easy to verify, and quite useful:
$$(x-y)^2+4xy=(x+y)^2.\tag{$2$}$$
Let $x=\cos^2 A$ and $y=\sin^2 A$. 
We get
$$4\sin^2 A\cos^2 A+(\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A)^2=(\cos^2 A+\sin^2 A)^2=1.$$